# How to turn off Microsoft Viva for my self?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

My employer has started up this annoying daily notification mails from Microsoft Viva. How do I turn this off (or get rid of it some other way)?

The manuals I found so far requires administrative rights and I have also tried to put up incoming rules in Outlook to redirect these mails to the bin and also marked it as spam. But every day it still reappears. Can I get rid of it?

Comment: Microsoft started to enable this on all tenants. Its more likely your employer did not enable this for you, but just doesn't see it as troubling that you get it. Ask your employer if you really need to get this, or that he can disable it globally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Open https://insights.viva.office.com
- authenticate
- click on gear icon (settings)
- if required click on settings link
- you can enable now Viva insights at all, Dashboard, digest mail, outlook add-in

Work fine for me

Comment: There's no option for me to disable emails

Comment: @MarkusMeyer, maybe its related to permissions your admin give you in Office365

Comment: Romeo, I'll try this. Let's see if there comes a new mail tomorrow.

Comment: Yes, it is working. I will mark this question as solved.

Thank you Romeo!

/Paul

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this document for your reference.
To stop receiving these emails, select Unsubscribe at the end of the email footer or unsubscribe at https://cortana.office.com/briefing.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/viva/insights/personal/briefing/be-faqs

And the rule in outlook doens't work because *the Briefing email is not a standard email. It's system-generated and does not go through the standard email delivery process. Instead, it's inserted directly into your Outlook inbox by Microsoft Viva. Briefing emails can't be managed by email rules or transport rules.*